# How to run pipeline only on branch and never on tag?

Tags: gitlab, devops, gitlab-ci, pipeline, gitlab-ci.yml

My `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_TAG
      when: never

stages:
- tmo
- test
- version
- build
```

but the pipeline still runs for tags. How do I get the desired behavior?

Comment: I think the rules are evaluated top to bottom. So you would need to skip the job (`when: never`) for tag-pipelines first, then check if it's in a branch.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong rules and should be updated to below:

Only runs when there is a commit branch, otherwise never runs.

```
- if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
- when: never
```

Comment: this still does not work